# Horosphere of a metric tree

Tags: metric-spaces, geometric-group-theory

I have a project I have to do. In order to do it I need to investigate W.E. Grosso's translation of "The Green Book" on Hyperbolic Group Theory, as found [here](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/ghys/articles/groupeshyperboliques-english.pdf).

I try to understand the term *horosphere* as defined on page 91.
I do not understand what kind of objects are in that set. Is it an ordered pair of elements of the tree? Perhaps there is a typo?

Here is the relevant excerpt:

> Let $X$ be a metric tree and $a$ a point on its boundary $\partial X$.
>   For $x,y \in X$, the distances $|x-a|$ and $|y-a|$ aren't defined; however, their difference $|y-a|-|x-a|$ is well defined.
>   More precisely, we define
>   $$ \beta_a (x,y) = |x-w|-|y-w| \in \mathbb{R}$$
>   where $w$ is a point on the intersetciob of the rays $[x,a)$ and $[y,a)$—we remark that the number $\beta_a(x,y)$ doesn't depend on the choice of $w$.
>
> [image: supporting diagram of beta_a (x,y)]
>
> **9. Definition.** The *horosphere* centered at $a \in \partial X$ is the set 
>   $\{ y \in X " \beta_a(x,y) = 0 \}$.

Comment: Consider making your question self-contained. It should not be required to follow your link in order to make sense of your question.

Comment: @ArthurFischer done. Is it it ok now ?

Comment: It's much better. Thanks. I'm not certain how much traction this will get here, as it seems a bit specialised. I assume that you are being advised by someone as you're working on this project; have you asked them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me point out that the terminology seems deficient: since $x$ is a parameter in the definition of a horosphere, it should be part of the terminology. In other words, one should speak of "The horosphere through $x$ centered at $a \in \partial X$", and as stated this is by definition equal to the set
$$\{y \in X \, | \, \beta_a(x,y)=0\}
$$
The set theory notation is quite clear on this issue: this horosphere is a set of points in $X$; each object in the horosphere is a point $y \in X$.

For instance, the specific point $x$ itself is in the horosphere because $\beta_a(x,x)=0$.

On the other hand, referring to the picture you drew, the specific point $y$ is NOT in the horosphere, because $\beta_a(x,y) = |x-w|-|y-w|$ is a positive number.

Here's a way to think of it intuitively. Imagine that you hang the tree on a wall, by putting a nail through the point $a$ and letting the tree hang downward from that point (of course, the point $a$ is infinitely far up, but perhaps your infinite imagination can deal with this anyway). Then the horosphere through $x$ is the subset of all points in the tree that are on the same horizontal level as $x$.